# GitHub action for golangci-lint fails with can't load fmt

Tags: go, github-actions

I'm using the GitHub action https://github.com/golangci/golangci-lint-action

I'm getting the error:

```sh
Installed golangci-lint into /home/runner/golangci-lint-1.43.0-linux-amd64/golangci-lint in 458ms
Prepared env in 606ms

run golangci-lint
  Running [/home/runner/golangci-lint-1.43.0-linux-amd64/golangci-lint run --out-format=github-actions] in [] ...
  panic: load embedded ruleguard rules: rules/rules.go:13: can't load fmt
  
  goroutine 1 [running]:
  github.com/go-critic/go-critic/checkers.init.9()
    github.com/go-critic/go-critic@v0.6.1/checkers/checkers.go:58 +0x4b4
  
  Error: golangci-lint exit with code 2
  Ran golangci-lint in 13383ms
```

Which is a known issue for `golangci-lint` with golang v1.18.0 https://github.com/golangci/golangci-lint/issues/2374

My GitHub action file is:

```yaml
name: golangci-lint
on:
  push:
    tags:
      - v*
    branches:
      - master
      - main
  pull_request:
permissions:
  contents: read
jobs:
  golangci:
    name: lint
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/setup-go@v2
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: golangci-lint
        uses: golangci/golangci-lint-action@v2
        with:
          version: v1.43
```

I've also tried to use:

```yaml
name: golangci-lint
on:
  push:
    tags:
      - v*
    branches:
      - master
      - main
  pull_request:
permissions:
  contents: read
jobs:
  golangci:
    strategy:
      matrix:
        go-version: [1.17.x]
    name: lint
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/setup-go@v3
        with:
          go-version: ${{ matrix.go }}
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: golangci-lint
        uses: golangci/golangci-lint-action@v2
        with:
          version: v1.43
```

But both are failing, what can I do in that case?

I have open this issue in the project, in case it helps https://github.com/golangci/golangci-lint-action/issues/442

Comment: I also faced this issue and able to solve by using latest version of golangci-lint under with clause. v1.46.2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bumping golangci/golangci-lint-action, actions/setup-go, and actions/checkout to v3 did the trick for me.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by `bumping` here? What does that mean?

Comment: @Dubby bumping means instead of using v2 use v3

Answer (score 0):

[Issue 442](https://github.com/golangci/golangci-lint-action/issues/442) is fixed by [PR 275](https://github.com/gabriel-vasile/mimetype/pull/275) and [commit 6ee1db2](https://github.com/gabriel-vasile/mimetype/commit/6ee1db2a660a68556166812c315f1205f47f3ab2) (v1.4.1), based [on comment](https://github.com/golangci/golangci-lint-action/issues/442#issuecomment-1099890561):

> The matrix keys do not seem to match, would correcting that solve the problem?

```yaml
    strategy:
      matrix:
        go-version: [1.17.x]
    name: lint
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/setup-go@v3
        with:
          go-version: ${{ matrix.go-version }}
```

---

And the current workaround mentioned in [issue 2374](https://github.com/golangci/golangci-lint/issues/2374#issuecomment-1152450356) by [Charlie Revett](https://github.com/revett):

> ```
> go version go1.17.11 darwin/arm64
> ```
>
> - Uninstall all versions of Go from Homebrew
> - Uninstall all versions of `golangci-lint` from Homebrew
> - Do some directory cleanup using `find / -type d -name go 2> /dev/null`
> - Do some directory cleanup using `find / -type d -name "golangci-lint" 2> /dev/null`
> - Install [`go1.17.11.darwin-arm64.pkg`](https://go.dev/dl/go1.17.11.darwin-arm64.pkg) via [`go.dev/dl`](https://go.dev/dl) using the installer (`.pkg`)
> - Install `golangci-lint` using `go install github.com/golangci/golangci-lint/cmd/golangci-lint@v1.46.2` ([current latest version](https://github.com/golangci/golangci-lint/releases)).
>   See "[Install from source](https://golangci-lint.run/usage/install/#install-from-source)"

Answer (score 0):

On my MacOS I simply removed all previous versions and installed the newest one by the following command

```
brew install golangci-lint
```

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the same issue here, and found that it's a problem when using the go 1.19 toolchain with `golangci-lint`.

If I run it with go 1.18, it works fine. With go 1.19, it fails with the same error as given here.

Answer (score 0):

My case is a little tricky.

I have `golangci-lint` installed from both `brew install` and `go get`. (That's why `brew install golangci-lint` or `brew upgrade golangci-lint` is not working for me...)

So I ran `which golangci-lint` first to see which one is not working, and then follow other answers here to upgrade it or reinstall it.